# Back to future popup not aligned correctly on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, april-fools, time-travel-mode

I think the popup was supposed to point to the clock icon, but seems a bit misaligned. It'll be better if the alignment is corrected.

[image]

Btw, great job!

Answer (score 5):

Good news! As of April 2, all April Fools bugs have been resolved. :)

Comment: How convenient...